# Understanding Gen.unit(x)

Tags: scala, monads

Working through [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), the book shows the `Gen Monad` definition. [Gen](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalacheck/Gen.scala?source=cc), as I understand, is a [ScalaCheck](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck) trait.

```
val genMonad = new Monad[Gen] {
    def unit[A](a => A): Gen[A] = Gen.unit(a)
    def flatMap[A, B](ma: Gen[A])(f: A => Gen[B]) = 
        ma.flatMap(f)
}
```

I believe that `OptionMonad.unit` is defined as `Some(a)`, but I don't understand `Gen.unit(a)`.

How is `Gen.unit(a)` defined?

Comment: Could you clarify what is `Gen`?

Comment: Hi Yury - thanks for that good question. I updated my question with a link to `Gen.scala`.

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.0.4/scalacheck-binding/src/main/scala/scalaz/scalacheck/ScalaCheckBinding.scala#L20

Comment: https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/testing/Gen.scala#L164

Comment: @Noah - my mistake. I was looking here (https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/7b962343a977d59e63d315b9622ac060203f643b/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/testing/Gen.scala) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Gen[A]` is just an object which can be repeatedly called to give instances of type `A`.  These "generators" are used to drive the ScalaCheck automated testing framework, which lets programmers specify properties of objects of a given type, and then repeatedly generates instances of that type and checks those properties.  Gen forms a monad, which is to say it supports the operations of "unit" and "bind", about which approximately a zillion tutorials can be found on the internet.   Scala's idioms for monads are a bit inconsistent, as monad types have a standard method of `bind`, called `flatMap`, but none for `unit`.  This is because Scala is object oriented, and `unit` doesn't take an object of it's monad, but instead returns one, so it doesn't make any sense to make `unit` a method of the underlying class.  Instead, most Scala monads leave the `unit` method implicit, often as a single-element constructor of the monad type.

So with that background out of the way, what's `unit` of `Gen[A]`.  Well it needs to be something which takes an object of type `A` as an argument, and then allows repeated generation of objects of type `A`.  Since `A` could literally be anything, there's really only one thing we can come up with which fits this bill.  `unit(a)`  must be a boring generator which repeatedly returns `a` .  Simple once you think it through.